# Extract first found int from String

Tags: java, regex, int

So I have Strings **22test12344DC** and **1name23234343dc**

I want the best way to extract the first found full int from a String.

So this would return 22 and 1 from the above examples. The first full int's found

I tried this way, but I don't want any values after the first char.

```
mystr.split("[a-z]")[0]
```

Comment: consider regex for matching numbers inside strings instead!

Comment: `I don't want any values after the first char.` how do you want to get 22 then

Comment: 22test12344DC  22 is the first int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
String s = "22test12344DC";
String firstInt = s.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(firstInt);
```

result:

```
22
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex and the right pattern will do the trick:
[here is one example](https://regex101.com/r/3ZJdA0/1)

```
Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\D+")
```

then break the while loop since you need only the 1st match

```
String myCodeString = "22test12344DC";
myCodeString = "1name23234343dc";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\D+").matcher(myCodeString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    break;
}
```